# How do I make those rhombic indents in this water bottle? Image in description

Tags: modeling

I'm relatively new. I know how to make a water bottle starting with a circle and extruding upwards while using a combo of extrude and scaling to make indents, but how would I do something like this? Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the shape, use the *Mirror, Array* and *Simple Deform* (*Bend* mode) modifiers:

Create a plane, rotate it, apply the rotation, subdivie, mirror:

[image]

Array it 6 times, make it bend with a *Simple Deform* modifier (*Bend* mode)

[image]

Change its shape, extrude inwards:

[image]

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add edge loops to sharp the edges:

[image]

As the medium part is divided by 4 and not 6, you're going to make it apart. Draw the curve with some extrusion, delete the faces to only keep the edges:

[image]

Create another plane, subdivide it so that it has the same number of edge loops as the bottom part (18 faces), use the previous shape to cut it with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Now again, mirror, array and bend with a *Simple Deform* modifier:

[image]

Extrude inwards, add edge loops:

[image]

Merge with the bottom:

[image]

Correct the shape etc:

[image]

You probably need half the edges, you can simplify whenever you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much